# Can conditional parameters be passed to a template? c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, conditional-statements

I am writing a template to abstract a buffer class. Can I pass conditional_variables as parameters to the template or do they need to be global? What is the best way to template this to abstract it without explicitly 'hardcoding' it in?

Comment: What is a "conditional variable"?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? It's hard to see what you're currently doing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: see [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use references to them:

```
template<std::condition_variable &> class F;
```

(or pointers, analogously). But this actually makes very little sense for the arguments to such a template should be very static and compile-time known, i.e. practically the very same globals.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks!